# asyncio: Stop coroutine on exception

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am writing a function that has to be self-restarted in case of catching an exception but I don't know how to do it.
I have this piece of code but it doesn't work.:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    while True:
        try:
            #REALLY huge amount of code
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception: {e}")
            # Here I want this script to run main() again
            return


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You first run `main()` to completion, then you set `running` to true. Subsequent loop iterations will find that `running` is true and do nothing. You need to describe in more detail what you expected to achieve.

Comment: post the actual code instead of pseudo-code

Comment: Judging from your code all you have to do is to remove `return` statement. But in real life such code would be broken. Some interrupt mechanism is almost surely necessary.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I edited this post to have the actual code

Comment: If you remove the `return` it’ll work as expected...

Comment: @deceze What if I need to stop already running coroutine of main() before starting a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function is a co-routine, and co-routines hold state. Re-starting the same one probably isn't a good idea. You want two functions, the co-routine `main`, and a regular function main that handles creating a new co-routine and running it again.

```py
async def amain():
    # Lot of code

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            asyncio.run(amain())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except Exception as e:
            log(e)
```

Something like that.